# What can cause copper pipe to corrode?

Tags: water, pipe

We have a corroded main water pipe that connects to a valve that goes into the house. The corroded pipe rises from the pave driveway and ends in a valve at the top.

Here's a picture:
[image]

The building inspector said this could be caused by improper grounding? Is this a cause?  What are some other causes?

Comment: [Causes of copper corrosion in plumbing systems](http://www.fwr.org/copper.pdf)

Comment: Where do you live, and how do you know the pipe is corroded?  What do you mean by "rises from driveway" - is this the valve top or does the pipe itself go thru the air to your house?

Comment: Pictures in this case, would be most helpful.

Comment: If the paving is concrete, and the pipe is not isolated from it, that alone will corrode the pipe. Then again, exposure to water and air will also corrode a copper pipe (or roof, for that matter) and result in verdigris... **how much** corrosion there is determines at what point it's "normal" and at what point it's a problem. Indeed, pictures. If this is normal for your neighborhood, pictures of some neighboring pipes might prove useful, too.

Comment: Interesting info on causes of copper corrosion. I believe the OP must have been talking about external corrosion. Copper in contact with Concrete can cause corrosion or if touching any ferrous metals corrosion may occur.  The last thing I can think of is strong cleaning agents used on cement / automotive cleaning could start corrosion. A clear lacquer spray paint will help eliminate corrosion, the pipe needs to be clean prior to application of the clear paint.

Comment: Copper doesn't rust. Only iron rusts. That's blackpipe or (was) galvanized. Welcome to your new house ;) You should learn how to sweat copper.

Comment: ... Because you have a [whole house that needs re-piping](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/92439/how-to-deal-with-a-corroded-copper-water-pipe/92508#comment134412_92508).

Comment: @Mazura - Why do you think the whole house needs re-piping?  The corroded part that goes down into the cement goes directly to the outside water meter.  The house is through the wall...

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - How would you describe the brown part of the pipe? Is that something else besides corrosion?  Are you saying that it possibly can be deposits?

Comment: @EdBeal Is there a way to clean the pipe without damaging it and causing some sort of pinhole?

Comment: RE. Why re-pipe? : Pex hasn't been around long enough to tell yet, but out of all the materials you can make a pipe out of, steel is the first to go. That's why, historically, we've used lead. And in commercial construction, it's copper all day for everything. I hate to sound overly dramatic, but galvanized pipe is a ticking time bomb. The only question is if it will clog completely before it rusts through. This may not happen in your lifetime, but it *will* happen in the foreseeable future. "need" (to re-pipe) is a far cry from 'must'. You're free to replace it piecemeal as you wish ;)

Comment: Pin holes are usually caused by high minerals or dielectric unions failing due to rust bridging the dielectric as @Ecnerwal pointed out if the exterior of the pipe is cleaned with scotch bright or plumbers abrasive and then a clear coat of lacquer it will stay bright on the outside. I did not see the photo before but that union may be the problem I would want to put a new dielectric union on there and clean it up.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your picture:

- Copper pipe in concrete; a problem.
- Copper pipe connected to galvanized iron pipe (evidently) without a dielectric union; a problem.
- Electrical ground connected to the galvanized iron pipe, not the copper pipe; likely also a problem, and would be a problem for the grounding if there was a dielectric union.

It is just possible that the union there is dielectric, in which case the copper above it and the ground wire above it are the main issues, but it's unlikely. A dielectric union is correctly used where the pipe material changes from copper to iron.

You could certainly start with a dielectric union and moving the ground wire (or having it moved by an electrician that knows what he or she is doing, unlike the one that put it there.)

Comment: That ground wire is for the cable system... I hope.

Comment: Are you saying that the strap between the two flow controls is for grounding?

Comment: I don't know of any other reason to strap a wire to a pipe.