# How to deal with a corroded copper water pipe?

Tags: water, pipe

We have a corroded copper pipe. I'm not interested in what caused the corrosion.  I just want to know how to treat it. What can I do to stop the corrosion? Paint it?  What would I paint it with?

UPDATE:
Please see this post for the condition of the pipe.
[What can cause copper pipe to corrode?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/92438/672)
Note: the corroded part is the main water line and the valve forward is to our structure.

Can we just replace the corroded section?

Answer (score 1):

Replacing it is the only viable option. You can buy a piece of pex and two push-on connectors for about $30 at your local home improvement store. The only tools you'll need are too cut the copper out and the pex to length - no tools needed for the connectors.

Comment: In this [particular case](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/92438/33) (though not mentioned here), the copper pipe is outdoors. Does that change your answer at all?

Comment: Yes. Pex will deteriorate from sunlight. You'd either need to build a cover around it, or replace the copper section with something else, like iron. But you need dielectric unions to connect iron pipe to copper.

Comment: Adding that information to your answer would be useful.

Comment: I just clicked on the link, and saw that it was posted from the same guy. Yeah, that thing has some major problems that make my answer completely useless. Unfortunately for the OP, the pipes in that house are most likely shot, although if they're iron he might get a few more years out of them. Although, the same can't be said for the copper main in the concrete. It'll have to go completely, and it'll be expensive.

Comment: That comment would make for a good answer there. In fact, these questions should be merged.

Comment: @jgrant Why did you conclude that the pipes in the house are shot?  The other post only shows this corrosion at the cement area.  This is where the water enters the house.  The house is beyond the valve...through the vertical wall.

Comment: I don't know for sure that the pipes are shot. That's just usually what I've seen. Metal pipes have a lifespan. Iron is usually around 50 years. Type L copper is usually around 40, type M is 25-30. These are very rough estimates because some things can accelerate the corrosion very quickly, like joining dissimilar metals (electrolysis), high acidity levels or low alkalinity levels, direct contact with the ground, etc. Likewise, if the pH and alkaline levels are managed well from the beginning, some metal pipe can greatly outlive my rough estimates.

Comment: My point is just that usually when I see a leak due to corrosion, the pipes are nearing the end of their lifespan. Usually, customers will confirm it with stories of leaks elsewhere in the house. But it's possible that the rest of the house was somewhat recently replumbed, and they just didn't do that part because it meant tearing out concrete. I've seen that before. Maybe you're lucky, and that's your situation. Good luck.